# Context free grammar for $L=\{a^n b c^n | n \ge0\}$

Tags: context-free

I'm having trouble with this problem. Can't find a CFG. Someone an idea?

$$L=\{a^n b c^n | n \ge0\}$$

Comment: I suggest to continue trying. It's not so difficult. Try to modify a grammar for $\{a^nc^n \mid n \geq 0\}$.

Comment: X-->epsilon | aXc   ? my problem is the b in the middle ...

Comment: Yes, you're very close. I suggest spending a few hours on this.

Comment: I'm thinking: S--> aAbBc,    A-->epsilon | aA,    B-->epsilon |Bc.  But that doesn't seem to work. That b  in the middle is confusing me. Can you give me a tip?

Comment: Derive the word a^2c^2 in your grammar and then modify the grammar such that you are able to derive a^2bc^2.

Comment: I've tried that, but whatever I try, the number of b is increasing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\begin{align}X&\to aXc\\ 
               X&\to b\end{align}$$

Comment: You got it! You can also write it as $X\to b\mid aXc$, like your previous example.

Comment: It would be a better answer if you explained why it worked -- that would be more helpful to anybody who's stuck on a question like this in the future.